# Postfix keeps saying wrong MySQL-Syntax

Tags: email, mysql, postfix

I have the following Postfix config-file to map an email to itself (All credentials are fictional):

```
user = db_mailuser
password = mailuser_password
hosts = 127.0.0.1
dbname = mailserver
query = SELCET email FROM virtual_users WHERE email='%s'
```

When I do (after restarting postfix):

```
postmap -q email@some.domain mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-email2email.cf
```

Then Postfix forwards the following MySQL message:

```
postmap: warning: mysql query failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELCET email FROM virtual_users WHERE email='email@some.domain'' at line 1
```

But at this point I am really confused, because the syntax is okay. I can go to mysql an query:

```
mysql> SELECT email FROM virtual_users WHERE email='email@some.domain'
```

And it says:

```
+-------------------------+
| email                   |
+-------------------------+
| email@some.domain       |
+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

What the hack could be wrong with my Postfix configuration?

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a true copy and paste, You spelled select wrong.  Its **select** not SELCET

DOH!!!  (Been there done that)

Comment: that is REALLY awkward... you are right.......